# I'm trying to create a running total which I am continually subtracting from

Tags: javascript

I want the total of my balance on a shopping site I'm designing to start at 1 million dollars, and have that amount decrease by the cost of any item whenever I add said item to my cart. I am trying to do this however I can only get this to work once for the first item, after that my code brings me back to my starting number before the next subtraction, therefore it isn't a running total. Any help?

What I have so far

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $("#balance").html(x);
        console.log(x);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $("#balance").html(x);
        console.log(x);
    });
});
var x=1000000
var y=20000
x=x-y
```

I have the console log feature there to show me whats happening, and after the first button click I get an output of 980,000 which is all good, but after the second time I get 980,000 again when I would expect 960,000.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform the subtraction in the event callback, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        x=x-y
        $("#balance").html(x);
        console.log(x);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button2").click(function(){
        x=x-y
        $("#balance").html(x);
        console.log(x);
    });
});
var x=1000000
var y=20000
```

```html
<button id="button1">button1</button>
<button id="button2">button2</button>

<span id="balance"></span>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract the `x` on the event click. Let's say you want to subtract each time button 2 clicked. then just do something like this. do the same for button 1 if you want subtracting happens on 1st button as well.

```js
..............
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button2").click(function(){
        x -= y;
        $("#balance").html(x);
        console.log(x);
    });
});

...........
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should have an object with items prices (use button ids as keys):

```
const prices = {
    button1: price1,
    button2: price2,
    ...other items...
}
```

And store the initial total in a variable:

```
var total = 1000000;
```

Then create a function to subtract the right amount when the corresponding button is clicked:

```
for (let button of ["button1", "button2", ...etcetera...]) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#"+button).click(function(){
        total -= prices[button];
        $("#balance").html(total);
    });
});
```

That's it!